# Unable to search on child entity using Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate on following `Master` entity on `name` field. It is working smooth. But, I also want to search on its child
entity `SubMaster's` `subName` field.

I have added `@IndexedEmbedded` and `@ContainedIn` annotations as specified in Hibernate Search docs. But, it is returning empty
when i try to search on `subName`.

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "master", catalog="mydb")
public class Master implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "seq", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer seq;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 45)
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "master")
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Set<SubMaster> subMasters = new HashSet<SubMaster>(0);

    //Getters and Setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_master", catalog="mydb")
public class SubMaster implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "seq", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer seq;

    @Column(name = "sub_name", length = 45)
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    private String subName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @ContainedIn
    private Master master = new HashSet<Master>(0);

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Search code:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
        .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Master.class).get();

org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb
      .keyword()
        .wildcard()
      .onFields("name", "subMasters.subName")
      .matching("*"+token.toLowerCase()+"*")
      .createQuery();

javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery =
        fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, Master.class);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Master> result = jpaQuery.getResultList();
```

**Indexes being built:**

name
_hibernate_class

Any help in right direction would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Hibernate Search do you use? How do you create and persist the entities (the code would help)?

Comment: @YoannRodière I am using version 5.7.1.Final and I am using EntityManager to persist entities. I have checked and indexes for Master is being created whenever i persist an entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who tried to help me. But, I have figured out the problem myself. I was using `hibernate tools` to generate entities from my database and generated entities had a attribute `catalog` in `@Table` annotation.

I removed this `catalog` attribute and re-indexed my entities and performed the search on `subMasters.subName` and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is a typo or not but:

```
.onFields("name", "subMaster.subName")
```

should be:

```
.onFields("name", "subMasters.subName")
```

with an s at the end of "subMasters".

When you're in this sort of situation, take a look at your index with Luke (https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases), it can help a lot.

Comment: Sorry, It's a typo. Corrected.

Comment: I have checked with luke and I am able to see `name`, `_hibernate_class` as available terms in my index and I believe `_hibernate_class` is my child entity. But, shouldn't it be `subMasters.subName` instead

Comment: You should have a field "subMasters.subName" in your "master" index. That's how Hibernate Search works. Be sure that you have reindexed the data with your latest code changes.

I don't know from where you paste your code but there is another typo in @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "subMaster"), it should be subMasters.

Maybe try to build a simple self contained test case with our template https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search/hibernate-search-lucene . It might be easier to see what's wrong with the concrete code.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. actually i have just renamed variables to put code here that's the reason for typos, i apologize. But, I have a working code for Master class but Sub Master is not working.

Comment: @GuilaumeSmet I have added a concrete project to demonstrate my problem. Pl. have a look at https://github.com/gschambial/hibernate-search-example